# Angular UI - Watch value from input in Popover Template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a directive which uses the Angular Bootstrap Popover, which contains an input. Everything works fine, except the watch is not triggering.

Here is a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uGei29uCy8gnncal4UJA?p=preview).

The directive looks like this:

```
angular.module('ngUserPopover', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.directive('userPopover', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            onSearch: '&',
        },
        templateUrl: 'myPopoverTemplate.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {

            scope.templateUrl = 'someTemplate.html'; // url for popover content template
            scope.searchText = 'Type something'; // initial sample value for input

            scope.$watch(function () {
                return scope.searchText;
            }, function () {
                // pass the new input value in the method...
                console.log(scope.searchText);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The `myPopoverTemplate.html` looks like:

```
<button uib-popover-template="templateUrl" popover-placement="right" popover-trigger="click" class="btn btn-default">Popover With Template</button>

<script id="someTemplate.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <div>{{dynamicPopover.content}}</div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" class="form-control">
    </div>
</script>
```

The button uses the [Angular Bootstrap UI popover](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#popover) directive, using a custom template which is the `someTemplate.html`.

The strange thing is the input inside the popover comes with the value define in `searchText` variable of my directive's scope, which is **'Type something'**, the watch executes once (you can see in the browser's console), but when you edit the input value, the watch doesn't fire anymore.

Since I'm using the angular bootstrap directive, I thought the `$watch` would work fine which the scope variable used for `ng-model` in my input, but it's not working (console.log is not being called when you edit the input's value).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the classic JS prototype inheritance issue. You need to make your `ngModel` an object and not a primitive, like so:

```
scope.model = {
  searchText: 'Type something'
};

scope.$watch(function() {
    return scope.model.searchText;
  }, 
  function () {
    // pass the new input value in the method...
    console.log(scope.model.searchText);
});
```

Then change your input's `ng-model`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="model.searchText"/>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/ocRBhNWLYUJ9hLE30U45?p=preview

If you really want to make your code clean, you can use a controller instead of the link function to handle your directive's logic, then you don't have to worry about the object vs primitive issue. Another improvement is to use `ngChange` instead of a watcher to handle changes to the input:

```
 link: function (scope, element, attr) {
   scope.templateUrl = 'someTemplate.html';
 },
 controllerAs: '$ctrl',
 controller: function($scope) {
   var $ctrl = this;
   $ctrl.searchText = 'Type something';

   $ctrl.inputChanged = inputChanged;

   function inputChanged() {
     console.log($ctrl.searchText);
   }
}
```

Template:

```
<input type="text" 
  ng-model="$ctrl.searchText" 
  ng-change="$ctrl.inputChanged()"
  class="form-control">
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/OfhoxXYCbf7AFYiAd5zL?p=preview

Comment: I can't believe I tried for like 6 hours debugging, googling around and this was the solution. You made my day, now I can sleep!!!